# Selector box question

Tags: html

What is the name of the html tool used for creating a list of objects from a select field. It usually looks like two boxes with an arrow in the middle. An example would be if you were creating a group and box A had a list of users and you would click on a name and then click the arrow in the middle. It would then add it to box B creating a unqiue group list. I am trying to find the name of this so I can find some examples online. Anyone know the name or where I can find some good examples?

Answer (score 1):

It's called Picklist. Google gives good examples with that keyword: http://google.com/search?q=html+picklist. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

try this

[Multi select transfer script](http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/easy-multi-select-transfer-with-jquery.html)

or this

[Option transfer](http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/optiontransfer/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML does not have this control built in. But many other environments provide it. Sometimes its called a doubleselect(struts2).

Comment: No, not as a single control, but two <select multiple> and two <button> elements usually suffice.